# Update cell with different text than dropbox selection

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform with a dropbox that contains different selections. That selection is then put into cell C3.

I want, depending on selection, a different text displayed. Eg: If I click "Test one" in the drop box then in C3 "Test one was selected" is displayed.

I tried different formulas.
I'm also unsure whether to add a module for this or put it somewhere in the code for the userform.

Comment: In the click event of the combobox, write the code to check what was selected and then write to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

So Ive figured it out! This is my new code

Private Sub Problem_ComboBox_Change()

Range("G3").Value = Problem_ComboBox.Text

If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Parts On ZMIT - Vendor" Then Range("G3").Value = "1.1"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Parts On ZMIT - Internal" Then Range("G3").Value = "1.2"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Parts Not On ZMIT" Then Range("G3").Value = "1.3"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Waiting On Parts Warehouse" Then Range("G3").Value = "1.4"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Waiting On Parts Runner" Then Range("G3").Value = "1.5"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Rework Internal Manufacture - Assembly" Then Range("G3").Value = "2.1"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Rework Internal Manufacture - Fabrication" Then Range("G3").Value = "2.2"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Rework Internal Manufacture - Machine Shop" Then Range("G3").Value = "2.3"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Rework Purchased - Assembly" Then Range("G3").Value = "2.4"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Rework Purchased - Fabrication" Then Range("G3").Value = "2.5"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Rework Purchased - Machine Shop" Then Range("G3").Value = "2.6"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Engineering / Design Problems" Then Range("G3").Value = "3.1"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "0-Series Build" Then Range("G3").Value = "3.2"
If Problem_ComboBox.Value = "Waiting On Packing List / Labels / Serial Plate" Then Range("G3").Value = "3.3"

End Sub